# How to compare timestamps in google sheets script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
var rawData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Raw Data')
var opVolging = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Opvolging')

var d = new Date();
var timeStamp = d.getTime();

function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow()
  var column = e.range.getColumn()
  // Edit on Opvolging Tab 
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Opvolging') {
    // If Dropdown 1 is edited
    if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'A6') {

      //Color value selected from dropdown
      var dropDownColor = e.range.getValue();
      //Get current User Timestamp from used dropdown
      var userTime = opVolging.getRange(row,column+1).getValue();
      
      //action if dropdown 1 is changed
      opVolging.getRange("V17").setValue(opVolging.getRange(row,column+1).getA1Notation());
      getCorrectColor(userTime, dropDownColor);
    }
  }
}

function getCorrectColor(userTime, userColor){
  //find time in 2nd column starting from 2nd row to 100 
  var data = opVolging.getRange(2, 2, 100).getValues();
  data.forEach((val, index) => {
      var rawDataTime = new Date(val);
      Browser.msgBox(rawDataTime+' / '+userTime);
      if(rawDataTime.valueOf() == userTime.valueOf()){
          Browser.msgBox('SUCCES!!!');
          setCorrectColor(userTime, userColor);
      }               
  })
}
```

This is what i have, keep in mind i am very new to this so my code will be very bad.
I'm trying to compare two timestamps, but eventhough both are the SAME timestamp, there's a difference in value. Any idea why?

Timestamp code 1 in Function onEdit
`var userTime = opVolging.getRange(row,column+1).getValue();`

Timestamp code 2 in function getCorrectColor
`var rawDataTime = new Date(val);`

If i compare both during my for each loop
this does not work `if(rawDataTime == userTime){`

i have read somewhere that i needed to use `if(rawDataTime.valueOf() == userTime.valueOf()){`
however when comparing both EVENTHOUGH they show me the same date time, their valueOf is slightly different.

Is there a way i can compare both reliably for my foreach?

Tried setting `var rawDataTime = val;` to `var rawDataTime = new Date(val);` since this was not recognised as a date otherwise.

Tried with and without `.valueOf()` both did not work eventhough when i print the values, both show the exact same date to the second.

Comment: Can you please share a sample spreadsheet so I can replicate your concern?

Comment: Just to add, Have you tried this: `var userTime = new Date(opVolging.getRange(row, column + 1).getValue());` ?

Comment: `if(rawDataTime.valueOf() == userTime.valueOf()){` This would be my recommendation. Would you please edit your question to provide values for `rawDataTime` and `userTime`.

Comment: If you change color i added a msgbox to see what both the outputs are left is "rawdatatime" (rawdatatime.valueof) / "usertime" (usertime.valueof) on the right side to show that eventhough the cell contains twice the same value, the valueof is different on the final (5th) msgbox. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: @Twilight please check my respons above, I was not aware I could tag people.

Comment: @Tedinoz please check my response above, I was not aware I could tag people.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code like this:

```
var rawData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Raw Data')
var opVolging = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Opvolging')

var d = new Date();
var timeStamp = d.getTime();

function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow()
  var column = e.range.getColumn()
  // Edit on Opvolging Tab 
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Opvolging') {
    // If Dropdown 1 is edited
    if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'A6') {

      //Color value selected from dropdown
      var dropDownColor = e.range.getValue();
      //Get current User Timestamp from used dropdown
      var userTime = new Date(opVolging.getRange(row,column+1).getValue()); // I added new Date() function
      
      //action if dropdown 1 is changed
      opVolging.getRange("V17").setValue(opVolging.getRange(row,column+1).getA1Notation());
      getCorrectColor(userTime, dropDownColor);
    }
  }
}

function getCorrectColor(userTime, userColor){
  //find time in 2nd column starting from 2nd row to 100 
  var data = opVolging.getRange(2, 2, 100).getValues();
  data.forEach((val, index) => {
      var rawDataTime = new Date(val);
      Browser.msgBox('"'+rawDataTime+'" ('+rawDataTime.valueOf()+') / "'+userTime+'" ('+userTime.valueOf()+')');
      if(rawDataTime.valueOf() == userTime.valueOf()){ // Added valueOf() so that it will convert to its Primitive type
          Browser.msgBox('SUCCES!!!');
          setCorrectColor(userTime, userColor);
      }               
  })
}

function setCorrectColor(userTime, userColor){

  //find time in 2nd column starting from 1st row to 100
  var data = rawData.getRange(2, 1, 100).getValues();
  data.forEach((val, index) => {
      var rawDataTime = new Date(val);
      if(rawDataTime.valueOf() == userTime.valueOf()){
          Browser.msgBox(rawDataTime+ " / "+userColor+' / '+index);
          //rawData.getRange()
      }               
  })
}
```

I have modified these lines:

- `var userTime = new Date(opVolging.getRange(row,column+1).getValue());`, added the `new Date() function` so that it will be created as a date object.
- In the `getCorrectColor` function, `if(rawDataTime.valueOf() == userTime.valueOf()){` I added the `valueOf()` so that it will convert to its primitive value.

Result:
[image]

*Please note:
I have changed the timezone for replication purpose only, you may changed it back to your necessary timezone.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer friend, i will test it out when i get back home. So if i understand correctly what i did wrong was using valueof to compare to the time when running the function which resulted in a time difference of a few miliseconds, you defined a time variable at the start of the script and compared the valueof to that time variable which does not change anymore. That's actually pretty smart lol, it made sense when i read it. Thanks a thousand times!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare two identical dates without success.

Try this script (using your own data) as a guide to comparing dates.

---

```
function debugDateMatch() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var opVolging = ss.getSheetByName('Opvolging')

  // Log the time zone of the script.
  var scriptTZ = Session.getScriptTimeZone()
  // Log the time zone of the spreadsheet.
  var ssTZ = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone()
  Logger.log("Time Zone: Script: "+scriptTZ+", spreadsheet: "+ssTZ)

  var b6Time = opVolging.getRange("B6").getValue()
  var b6newTime = new Date(b6Time)
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Value in cell B6: "+b6Time+", 'new Date(B6)': "+b6newTime+", b6 valueOf: "+b6Time.valueOf()+", 'new Date(B6)' valueOf:"+b6newTime.valueOf())

  // get the data in Column B
  var data = opVolging.getRange("B2:B6").getValues()
  //Logger.log(data) // DEBUG

  // loop through Column B values
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var colbnewTime = new Date(data[i][0])
    //Logger.log("i:"+i+", celltime"+data[i][0]+", newtime"+colbnewTime+", raw value: "+data[i][0].valueOf()+", newtime value:"+colbnewTime.valueOf())

    if (b6Time.valueOf()=== data[i][0].valueOf()){
      Logger.log("DEBUG: MATCH: Row#:"+(+i+2)+", cell value: "+data[i][0]+", 'new Date(cell value)': "+colbnewTime+", cell valueOf: "+data[i][0].valueOf()+", 'new Date(cell value)' valueOf: "+colbnewTime.valueOf())
    }else{
    Logger.log("DEBUG: NO MATCH: Row#:"+(+i+2)+", cell value: "+data[i][0]+", 'new Date(cell value)': "+colbnewTime+", cell valueOf: "+data[i][0].valueOf()+", 'new Date(cell value)' valueOf: "+colbnewTime.valueOf())
    }
  }
}
```

---

**RESULTS**

```
DEBUG: No MATCH: b6valueOf: 1692918283797 <> Row#:2 cellvalueOf: 1692838800000
DEBUG: No MATCH: b6valueOf: 1692918283797 <> Row#:3 cellvalueOf: 1692914978086
DEBUG: No MATCH: b6valueOf: 1692918283797 <> Row#:4 cellvalueOf: 1692918167206
DEBUG: No MATCH: b6valueOf: 1692918283797 <> Row#:5 cellvalueOf: 1692918221142
DEBUG: MATCH: b6valueOf: 1692918283797 == Row#:6 cellvalueOf: 1692918283797
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the answer friend, i will test it out when i get back home. So if i understand correctly what i did wrong was using valueof to compare to the time when running the function which resulted in a time difference of a few miliseconds, you defined a time variable at the start of the script and compared the valueof to that time variable which does not change anymore. That's actually pretty smart lol, it made sense when i read it. Thanks a thousand times!

Comment: `you defined a time variable at the start of the script and compared the valueof to that time variable which does not change anymore.` Um, I think so ;) I wanted to see if there was a difference between date in cell B6 (`b6Time`), and `new Date (b6Time)` (as well as the `valueOf` of both values) - and there is _no_ difference.  FWIW, the script is just an exercise in debugging. This line is the key: it displays the value of all the variants `Logger.log("i:"+i+", celltime"+data[i][0]+", newtime"+colbnewTime+", raw value: "+data[i][0].valueOf()+", newtime value:"+colbnewTime.valueOf())`.

Comment: hi, are you perhaps able to help me out further and optimise my code? I'm willing to pay you for your efforts, since i'm not quite sure if the steps i have to take after these functions are the correct ones i am taking.

Comment: Are you trying to insert this code into your existing function?

Comment: I got the code working as i wanted it to so thanks for that, i even added dynamic dropdowns depending on how many new users we get. So i am more then happy with the result of the 'Opvolging' page. But this was just one thing of a few things we need, and i'm starting to wonder if i took the right approach. Hence why i perhaps could explain to you what we actually need and you could direct me in the right direction?

Comment: I do understand but I'm sorry, I'm unable to commit to the time available.